# What can be said about a matrix and an eigenvector when their eigenvalue is large?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to understand the Harris Corner Detector.  It detects the presence of corners within a window if their pixels have large eigenvalues for the matrix

\begin{bmatrix}I_x^2&I_xI_y\\I_xI_y&I_y^2\end{bmatrix}

where $I_x$ is the horizontal gradient of a pixel, and $I_y$ is the vertical gradient.

I'm trying to understand what values those elements ( $I_x^2, I_xI_y, I_y^2$ ) have to take, for the matrix to have a large eigenvalue.

In a broader sense, I'm trying to understand what do the elements of a matrix, $M$, have to be for it to have large eigenvalues.  Does $M_{11}$ have to be large?  Does $M_{11}/M_{12}$ have to be the same ratio as $M_{21}/M_{22}$?

In terms of the Harris Detector, I know that it responds well to more than one gradient within the window... I'm trying to understand how $I_x^2, I_xI_y, I_y^2$ and how those elements are manipulated to expresses "cornerness".

The main question is: **how must elements of a matrix be related to one another to create large eigenvalues?**

Comment: Is each $I$ just a number formed by taking some linear combination of the  intensity of some neighboring pixels?

Comment: @JessicaK As far as I can tell from the papers and powerpoints I've been reading, yes, $I_x$ is the intensity of the right pixel minus the intensity of the left pixel.  $I_y$ is calculated similarly.

Comment: In that case, you can directly compute the eigenvalues. Notice that the determinant of the matrix is 0. So $\lambda = 0$ is an eigenvalue, the other eigenvalue therefore must be the trace $I_{x}^{2} + I_{y}^{2}$. On the wikipedia on corner detection, they use something different to avoid this. (Which I am not familiar with)

Comment: @JessicaK thanks for succintly explaining how to get the eigenvalue.  That was the easiest to understand.  Though, I can't intuit how the elements work together to generate a large eigenvalue from that.  Thanks anyway :D

Comment: As formulated in your question, 0 is always an eigenvalue. The other eigenvalue is $I_{x}^{2} + I_{y}^{2}$. So if the difference in intensities in either the x or the y direction is large your eigenvalue will be large. If the difference in intensities of x and y are both small you will have a very small eigenvalue.